# Recognizing a link on a website to click on it in a using screen visual only

Tags: python, html, machine-learning

What I want to do is to write a Python script to recognize a specific link and make a left-click on it. To be more explanatory, here are two images from websites:

**Page 1**
[image: link1]
and
**Page 2**
[image: link2]

I want the script to click on "enter site" in page 1 and "try again" on page 2. If possible I want to use machine learning having only the screen image input. It is probably easier to go through the site source, but I want to be further challenged. I gave this a thought but couldn't figure out where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Using screen visual only, you can use:

```
import pyautogui
```

and then look for the
`pyautogui.locateOnScreen()` or `pyautogui.locateCenterOfScreen()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.youradress.org")#put here the adress of your page
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")#put here the content you have put in Notepad, ie the XPath
print(elem .get_attribute("class"))
driver.close()
```

you can get the class of the html element, or its id, and then pass it to the script and do whatever you want.